# Why is the muon decay a Flavor Changing Charged Current (FCCC) process?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction

One way of understanding why the muon decay $$\mu^-\to e^-+\bar{\nu}_e+\nu_\mu\tag{1}$$ is a **C**harged **C**urrent (CC) process is to write the intermediate step through which the decay (1) proceeds i.e., $$\mu^-\to \nu_\mu+\color{red}{W^-}\to \nu_\mu+\color{red}{e^-+\bar{\nu}_e}.\tag{2}$$ Now the intermediate step explains that since the process is mediated by charged current interaction or the $W$ boson, it is a **C**harged **C**urrent (CC) process. But what makes the process **F**lavor **C**hanging (FC)? You can find this term [here](http://webtheory.sns.it/ggilectures2016/nir_slides/Nir.pdf). As far as I can see, the process (1) or (2) conserves the total as well as individual lepton numbers $L_e,L_\mu,L_\tau$. Does one define a flavor number or something?

Comment: ? This is a highly nonstandard, and as you are pointing out, semantically fraught term. Where did you get it?

Comment: What would you call a hadronic CC decay of the *τ* lepton?

Comment: It makes more sense in the quark sector, where different quarks of the same generation have different flavour. $\mu \to \nu_\mu$ is analogous to $c \to s$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos See here http://webtheory.sns.it/ggilectures2016/nir_slides/Nir.pdf

Comment: @CosmasZachos "_All charged current couplings involve nontrivial mixing matrices, and so may easily change generation_" In the flavour basis, the CC Lagrangian does not have any mixing between generations. It is only in the mass basis a nontrivial mixing matrix appears (as in your answer). Therefore at a given vertex, the CC interaction cannot change lepton flavour or generation. Though, the CC Lagrangian can cause $s\to u$ transition at a vertex while $\mu^-\to \nu_e$ is not possible!

Comment: No.... flavor is defined by mass eigenstates, and so is generation. You must always consider mass eigenstates to assay FC. That is why lepton couplings are even maximally FC on occasion, in this definition...

Comment: @CosmasZachos "_flavor is defined by mass eigenstates_" I don't get this. In literature, $\nu_e,\nu_\mu$ and $\nu_\tau$ are called flavors or generations but $\nu_1,\nu_2,\nu_3$ denote mass eigenstates. They don't coincide. In fact, flavour oscillations happen precisely because of this reason as you know!

Comment: If anyone used $\nu_{e,\mu,\tau}$ for "flavored state" or assigned "generation" to them, challenge them *hard*. They are clearly confused. They may have been misreading the hierarchy question.

Comment: Flavor is defined by mass eigenstates indeed. I keep repeating that $ν_{μ,e,τ}$ are definitions of the "interaction-vertex-convenience arrays" that straddle generations, consisting of superpositions of real, physical, propagating $ν_{1,2,3}$s. As a result, e.g., $ν_{\tau}$ mixes generations virtually maximally. The CC, of course, changes charge, so flavor is a profoundly misleading substitute for "generation". Devising bases where nothing apparently happens cannot change the physics.

Comment: The process is called "Flavor Changing" in the loose sense that a charged lepton of a particular generation is no longer a charged lepton of that generation, by analogy to flavor changing charged current interactions in quarks.

Comment: @ohwilleke. Precisely; I review in my answer why there is hardly any pointed information content therein, however. The logical tension is reflected in the very title of this question.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/neutrino-oscillations-versus-cmk-quark-mixing).

Comment: [Also related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76804/mixing-of-quarks-neutrinos-and-leptons/253751#253751).

Answer (score 2):

When you write the SM Lagrangian in terms of mass eigenstates, charge current couplings (*W*) involve generation-mixing matrices, the CKM for quarks and the PMNS for leptons. By sharp contrast, there is no mixing for neutral current couplings (*Z*), and generation mixing enters delicately (GIM-suppressed) at the 2-*W* exchange, so, then loop level—it runs on the CKM matrices of the charge current couplings!

A hadronic decay going through a *W* exchange $B\to \psi K$ thus mutates flavor of the *same charge*, a *b* to an *s*, thereby slipping down from the 3rd to the 2nd generation. Or $\Lambda \to p \pi^-$, an *s* to a *d*, from the 2nd to the first. Such flavor mutations of fermions of the same charge, *all else being unremarkable*, are dubbed "flavor changing", *FC*.

You might, ill-advisedly, marvel at the *μ* to *e* mutation as such a generational slip, and call it lepton-flavor changing, too. (But, neutrino Lepton flavor was *invented* to provide conservation agreement, as you note, trivially, at the interaction vertex. It has *no analogy* to quark flavors, and, unlike them, it is *not conserved* in propagation: the entire point of neutrino oscillations! This is why people repeatedly stress the "nonphysicality" of $\nu_{e,\mu,\tau}$, a shared fiction).

- Again: The $\nu_{μ,e}$ neutrinos you wrote  are not mass eigenstates ($\nu_{3,2,1}$ , real, propagating particles of the fundamental SM); they are "interaction-convenience combination states",  specifically invented to conserve lepton flavors in the SM interactions, $L_e,L_\mu,L_\tau$, but not in kinetic terms.

They thus straddle generations (characterized by mass stratification) through the PMNS matrix, mixing generations thoroughly, far more violently than the CKM. One has not even assigned generations to the mass eigenstates, yet, before resolution of the mass hierarchy question. The consensus is that there is *no point* in discussing such, yet, unless you were building recondite models. The jumble of neutrino and antineutrino components on the right hand side of your (2), then, involves all 3 generations and makes a mockery out of "flavor" and FC, since it cannot be ignored.

I hope you can see why it hardly makes sense to be discussing FCCC, at all—even though 30 years ago people were actually discussing the $\Delta S =1$ part of the effective weak hamiltonian, subdominant to the strangeness preserving part, just because CKM mixing is small...

I should contrast the above to the  substantial utility of the sound FCNC concept, which usefully demarcates small loop corrections of a SM Lagrangian principle—but that would entail mission creep.

---

- A teaching moment reminder, in response to comments:

Much of the popular misconceptions of flavor violations hinge on the misbegotten terms "flavor basis" and "flavor eigenstates" for $\nu_{e,\mu,\tau}$. You may see the peril of the term if you slip back to the 60s and recall the convenience superposition array coupling to the up quark in the charged weak current. That state, $d~'\equiv d \cos\theta_C+s \sin\theta_C$, where the angle is the so-called Cabbibo angle (discovered by Gell-Mann and Levy), is not a mass eigenstate. Therefore it *has no well-defined flavor*: it provides access to two flavors, *d* and *s*, defined *through* the quark mass eigenstates. It is called "in the flavor basis", since it couples to the *u* flavor in the charged weak vertex. (It underlies the FCCC dispatched above). It would be superflous upon sticking to the mass basis and writing down the CKM matrix in the action, which everybody does, today.

Likewise,
$\nu_{e,\mu,\tau}$ are convenience superpositions which remind one that in a vast swath of reactions where neutrino oscillations have not changed their identity, $\nu_{e,\mu,\tau}$ are practical reminders that the charged lepton generation they are associated with in production will be mostly the same in their charge current absorption, usually their primary handle of observation. But, *lacking a well-defined mass, they do no possess a well-defined generation*, even though it is their mutation in neutrino oscillations (free propagation!) that is informally dubbed "lepton flavor change".

The all-time popular confusion is reflected in  widespread poster charts of the standard model generations. These charts tabulate mass eigenstates for quarks, (u,c,t; d,s,b), on the one hand; but, instead of presenting the analog for leptons, real particles (e,μ,τ; ν<sub>1</sub>,ν<sub>2</sub>,ν<sub>3</sub>), assuming the normal hierarchy prevails, they instead stick in the interaction states (ν<sub>e</sub>,ν<sub>μ</sub>,ν<sub>τ</sub>), conferring a misconstrued physical significance to them and all but inviting the logical quandaries dispatched here.

Comment: The PMNS Matrix governs neutrino oscillations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo%E2%80%93Maki%E2%80%93Nakagawa%E2%80%93Sakata_matrix Unlike the CKM matrix, it doesn't apply to the charged current weak interactions via the W boson of leptons. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction#Charged-current_interaction Charged current weak interactions in leptons are governed instead by the principle of lepton universality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton#Universality The PMNS matrix instead governs flavor-mass eigenstate neutrino oscillation with no SM mediating particle.

Comment: Your first statement is correct, but your second is flat wrong. The CKM and the PMNS are mathematically similar, and, in the flavor basis, quarks *do* obey a universality of sorts indeed, and hence hadrons: that's *exactly* how Gell-Mann and Levy discovered Cabbibo mixing in 1960 to start with! If you are advocating a deep conceptual (as opposed to circumstantial) contrast between lepton and quark mixings and couplings, you are quite wrong, and you might as well ask a separate question.

Comment: Explain how the PMNS matrix has anything to do, for example, with the charged current decay of a tau lepton via W bosons? The CKM matrix and the PMNS matrix are mathematically similar. But, the PMNS matrix applies to flavor v. mass in neutrinos, and doesn't have any applicability to charged leptons, while the CKM matrix applies to all quarks. And, the oscillations described by the PMNS matrix are not W boson mediated events.

Comment: You are confused. Both the CKM and the PMNS matrices convert mass eigenstates of the lower weak isodoublet component to linear combinations thereof coupling to the upper isocomponent via a *W*. This is no different for the $\nu_\tau$ you are asking about. Again, a neutrino of a given lepton flavor is a shared fiction: a state which does not propagate. Indeed, "lepton flavor" oscillations  do recall the W involved in their production and that involved in their absorption! These are the ones that change, not the propagating mass eigenstates! Do ask a dedicated question if you are still confused.