# What will happen if neutrinos are not massless particles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, mass, nuclear-physics, neutrinos

In beta decay, explain qualitatively What will happen if neutrinos are not massless particles?

Comment: ? But they are not. What do you mean?

Comment: @Cosmos Zachos We usually consider them as a massless in beta decay.

Comment: You just normally ignore their mass because it is so preternaturally ***small***  in comparison to any other scale in the problem. You want the first perturbative correction in the neutrino mass? Why? It is freakishly small.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15320/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644270/2451 and links therein.